# Informatica Model Repository Service has no content

Tags: oracle, informatica

I am trying to install Informatica IDQ on Windows 7 64-bit. I created a bigfiles, but I am still getting no content error. I have Oracle, and I used the below query for creating a big file.

```
create BIGFILE TABLESPACE CMX_DATA
NOLOGGING
DATAFILE 'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\CMX_DATA1.dbf' SIZE 3000M REUSE
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL;
```

but I am still getting an `ora_01658 unable to create INITIAL extent for segment` error.

```
Could not execute action... 
The requested operation could not be performed due to the following error : [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] 
[DBPERSISTER_2015] Failed to upgrade the Model repository. This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] 
[DBPERSISTER_2015] Failed to upgrade the Model repository. This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] 
[DBPERSISTER_0017] Failed to create table '"IDQMRS".PO_ISPLONG.' 
  Verify that a table with the same name does not exist and that the database user has sufficient privileges. 
  This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the name of the tablespace:

> ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SYSTEM

The installation is trying to create the tablespace in the **SYSTEM** tablespace. So it really doesn't matter how space you've allocated to CMX_DATA, your installer ain't using it.

This is wrong: only Oracle's internal schemas should be writing to the SYSTEM tablespace. There must be something awry in the configuration of the Informatica installer or the definition of the IDQMRS user. You need to go back over the steps to find the place where you need to specify the destination tablespace and correct it.